# recyclerview with volley loading more datas and display it into UI taking more time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

- I'm using Recyclerview to load more than 200 datas to display in home
  page.
- Volley taking 3 minutes loader initially.then after three to four
  seconds, recycler view loading more than 200 datas in adapter.So
  totally it takes seven seconds to load the image contents to display
  it into UI in home page.
- But I have to load images in only three seconds.is it possible to do?
  If I get any suggestion regarding to this it will be helpful to me.

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
        if(createdBy.equals("event")){

            String eventName = jsonObject.getString("name");
            String eventDate = jsonObject.getString("event_date");
            String eventMonthYear = jsonObject.getString("event_date_year");
            String eventLocation = jsonObject.getString("location");

            homePostItems.setEventPost(createdBy);
            homePostItems.setEventName(eventName);
            homePostItems.setEventDate(eventDate);
            homePostItems.setEventMonthYear(eventMonthYear);
            homePostItems.setEventLocation(eventLocation);

            }

            if(createdBy.equals("post")){

             homePostItems.setPostData(createdBy);

              }

           homePostItems.setSharePopup("socialAndGolive");

           homePostItemsList.add(homePostItems);

           homePostitemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**HomeAdapter.java:**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    if (rowItem.getEventPost() != null) {
        if (rowItem.getEventPost().equals("event")) {

            holder.rlPostItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ivPostFlag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userMenuImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ivPostedImage.setClickable(false);
            holder.rlEventDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvSubtitle.setText("Event");
            holder.tvDateEvent.setText(rowItem.getEventDate());
            holder.tvMonthYearEvent.setText(rowItem.getEventMonthYear());
            holder.tvNameEvent.setText(rowItem.getEventName());
            holder.tvAddressEvent.setText(rowItem.getEventLocation());

            Typeface typeDate = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "kausan.otf");
            holder.tvDateEvent.setTypeface(typeDate);

            Typeface typeName = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "abz.ttf");
            holder.tvMonthYearEvent.setTypeface(typeName);


        } else {

            holder.rlEventDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    } else {
        holder.rlEventDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do not load your 200 items at once, load only datas which is enough to fill your Recyclerview, then when the user scrolls unto it then thats another time to download another batch of data until you completed your 200 items. When the user doesn't scroll that much then there is no point to complete downloading all 200 items.

Comment: @Enzokie ok.let me try that suggestion and tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Actual process of recycler view not loading all the images
  initially.**For Example**, I'm having more than 300 images to load in
  home page.
- Recyclerview won't load all images initially.I used
  `NestedSCrollView` inside recyclerview.So that all 300 images will
  load initially.it took 7 seconds more to load the home page.
- Removing nested scroll view solved my issue.You can refer
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103183/nested-scrollview-inside-recyclerview-not-triggering-onscrolllistener-when-scrol)
  and
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073376/recyclerview-with-endless-scrolling-in-nestedscrollview-triggers-onscrolled)
  to understand when pagenation with recyclerview also not working when
  using nested scroll view.